# User Interface Design Overflowing while rendering data items in List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a UI design that looks a little messed up at the moment and I've gone totally blank as to what more I could do to fix this. All I do right now is just keep staring at the code only to figure out no solution at all. The idea is to render a list with the data received from the server response. You would find the code and the JSON response below. Please note that the reason behind using the for loops is to render the data that is nested inside of the list in the response.

The issue:

[image]

As you can tell, Every image should have the text and the prices written next to them and not the way it is now. Then on the next line, the next item needs to get rendered in the same way, and so on. I have marked the exact code with a comment.

My code:

```
    class RecentItems extends StatefulWidget {
      RecentItemsState createState() => RecentItemsState();
    }
    
    class RecentItemsState extends State<RecentItems> {
      bool isLoading = true;
      // bool isExpanded = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        Provider.of<OrderHistoryProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .getOrderHistory()
            .then((_) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final tabLayout = width > 600;
        final largeLayout = width > 350 && width < 600;
        // final textScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;
        final provider = Provider.of<OrderHistoryProvider>(context).orderHistory;
    
        // TODO: implement build
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.04, right: width * 0.04),
          child: isLoading
              ? const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  // height: height * 0.7,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Recent Orders',
                            // // textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: tabLayout
                                    ? 25
                                    : largeLayout
                                        ? 17
                                        : 12),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => PendingOrders())),
                            child: Text(
                              'View All',
                              // // textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: tabLayout
                                      ? 18
                                      : largeLayout
                                          ? 14
                                          : 10),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: height * 0.04),
                      ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: width * 0.02, right: width * 0.02),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: tabLayout
                                    ? height * 0.14
                                    : largeLayout
                                        ? height * 0.1
                                        : height * 0.12,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(width * 0.01,
                                    height * 0.005, width * 0.02, height * 0.005),
                                margin: provider['data'][index]['order_details']
                                            ['isExpanded'] ==
                                        true
                                    ? const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0)
                                    : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.04),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: provider['data'][index]
                                                ['order_details']['isExpanded'] ==
                                            true
                                        ? const BorderRadius.only(
                                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                            topRight: Radius.circular(20))
                                        : BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    boxShadow: const [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          blurRadius: 5,
                                          offset: Offset(0, 2))
                                    ]),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.02),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            provider['data'][index]['order_details']
                                                ['order_number'],
                                            // // textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: tabLayout
                                                    ? 25
                                                    : largeLayout
                                                        ? 17
                                                        : 12),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
                                          Text(
                                            provider['data'][index]['order_details']
                                                ['created_at'],
                                            // // textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.grey[600],
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: tabLayout
                                                    ? 18
                                                    : largeLayout
                                                        ? 12
                                                        : 8),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        width: tabLayout
                                            ? width * 0.3
                                            : largeLayout
                                                ? width * 0.1
                                                : width * 0.25),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        FittedBox(
                                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                          child: Text(
                                            '₹${provider['data'][index]['order_details']['grand_total']}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: tabLayout
                                                    ? 50
                                                    : largeLayout
                                                        ? 17
                                                        : 12),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              print(
                                                  'length: ${provider['data'][index]['order_products'].length}');
                                              print(
                                                  'isExpanded: ${provider['data'][index]['order_details']['isExpanded']}');
                                              setState(() {
                                                provider['data'][index]
                                                            ['order_details']
                                                        ['isExpanded'] =
                                                    !provider['data'][index]
                                                            ['order_details']
                                                        ['isExpanded'];
                                              });
                                            },
                                            child: Icon(!provider['data'][index]
                                                    ['order_details']['isExpanded']
                                                ? Icons.arrow_drop_down
                                                : Icons.arrow_drop_up))
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              //The code that's causing this
                              if (provider['data'][index]['order_details']
                                      ['isExpanded'] ==
                                  true)
                                Container(           
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: height * 0.04),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            blurRadius: 5,
                                            offset: Offset(0, 2))
                                      ]),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    height: height * 0.2,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    child: ListView(
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            for (int itemDetails = 0;
                                                itemDetails <
                                                    provider['data'][index]
                                                            ['order_products']
                                                        .length;
                                                itemDetails++)
                                              Container(
                                                width: width * 0.2,
                                                height: height * 0.06,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                    border: Border.all(
                                                        color: Colors.green,
                                                        width: 2)),
                                                child: ClipRRect(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                  child: Image.network(
                                                    'http://54.80.135.220${provider['data'][index]['order_products'][itemDetails]['product']['main_image']}',
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            SizedBox(width: width * 0.02),
                                            Column(
                                              children: [
                                                for (var itemDetails
                                                    in provider['data'][index]
                                                        ['order_products'])
                                                  Text(
                                                    '${itemDetails['product']['name']} ${itemDetails['product']['weight']}${itemDetails['product']['uom']['short_name']}',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.bold),
                                                  ),
                                                for (int itemDetails = 0;
                                                    itemDetails <
                                                        provider['data'][index]
                                                                ['order_products']
                                                            .length;
                                                    itemDetails++)
                                                  Text(
                                                      '₹${provider['data'][index]['order_products'][itemDetails]['price']} x ${provider['data'][index]['order_products'][itemDetails]['quantity']} ')
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        itemCount: provider['data'].length > 3
                            ? 3
                            : provider['data'].length,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
        );
      }
    }
```

The JSON Response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Order list fetched successfully",
    "data": [
        {
            "order_details": {
                "id": 14,
                "address": {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "Rachhel Sekh2",
                    "contact_number": "9641355412",
                    "postcode": "700079",
                    "address_line": "48 Tarunsen Gupta Sarani Road 1",
                    "locality": "Dum Dum 1",
                    "city": "Kolkata 1",
                    "state": "West Bengal 1",
                    "save_address_as": "Home",
                    "is_default": true,
                    "map_lat": "22.643824",
                    "map_lng": "88.426776",
                    "user": 14
                },
                "created_at": "2022-06-13T13:06:22.901003+05:30",
                "updated_at": "2022-06-13T13:06:22.930737+05:30",
                "order_number": "ORD4726409566",
                "price": "1740.00",
                "shipping_charge": "0.00",
                "tax": "71.60",
                "grand_total": "1630.44",
                "offer_code": "KOL96",
                "offer_discount": "181.16",
                "payment_method": "COD",
                "payment_status": "Pending",
                "order_status": "Order Placed",
                "user": 14,
                "delivery_exe": null
            },
            "order_products": [
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "price": "160.00",
                    "quantity": 7,
                    "total_price": "1120.00",
                    "product": {
                        "id": 13,
                        "created_at": "2022-06-13T00:52:17.284597+05:30",
                        "updated_at": "2022-06-13T00:52:17.284649+05:30",
                        "name": "Oats",
                        "short_description": "Oats",
                        "description": "Oaaaaaaatsssssss",
                        "status": "in_stock",
                        "weight": "1",
                        "qty": 20,
                        "price": 160.0,
                        "tax": "5.00",
                        "main_image": "/media/product_module/product/image_picker2440066848872026571.jpg",
                        "soft_delete": false,
                        "category": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-10T13:03:51.772459+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-10T13:03:51.772503+05:30",
                            "name": "Grocery and Staples",
                            "categoryImage": "/media/product_module/category/41619-7-groceries-free-download-image-thumb.png",
                            "active": true
                        },
                        "sizes": {
                            "id": 4,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:48:05.957406+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:48:05.957440+05:30",
                            "size": "large"
                        },
                        "brand_name": null,
                        "uom": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:49:10.746284+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:49:10.746317+05:30",
                            "name": "Kilogram",
                            "short_name": "Kg"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "price": "100.00",
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "total_price": "300.00",
                    "product": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "created_at": "2022-06-05T22:55:36.543639+05:30",
                        "updated_at": "2022-06-13T00:41:32.279753+05:30",
                        "name": "Apple",
                        "short_description": "Apllleeee",
                        "description": "Appleeee Le Looooooo",
                        "status": "out_of_stock",
                        "weight": "200",
                        "qty": 30,
                        "price": 100.0,
                        "tax": "2.00",
                        "main_image": "/media/product_module/product/image_picker1124916014311738168.jpg",
                        "soft_delete": false,
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:42:24.973439+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:57:04.123793+05:30",
                            "name": "Fruits and Vegetables",
                            "categoryImage": "/media/product_module/category/png-transparent-graphy-vegetable-fruit-basket-of-vegetables-natu_lvwqkfm.png",
                            "active": true
                        },
                        "sizes": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:47:55.172720+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:47:55.172755+05:30",
                            "size": "medium"
                        },
                        "brand_name": null,
                        "uom": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:49:27.640236+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:50:18.553700+05:30",
                            "name": "Gram",
                            "short_name": "gm"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "price": "160.00",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "total_price": "320.00",
                    "product": {
                        "id": 12,
                        "created_at": "2022-06-07T19:39:58.277106+05:30",
                        "updated_at": "2022-06-13T13:26:17.541253+05:30",
                        "name": "Mango",
                        "short_description": "Banginapalli",
                        "description": "fresh and juicy",
                        "status": "out_of_stock",
                        "weight": "4",
                        "qty": 35,
                        "price": 160.0,
                        "tax": "3.00",
                        "main_image": "/media/product_module/product/image_picker5640335828307412875.jpg",
                        "soft_delete": false,
                        "category": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:42:24.973439+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:57:04.123793+05:30",
                            "name": "Fruits and Vegetables",
                            "categoryImage": "/media/product_module/category/png-transparent-graphy-vegetable-fruit-basket-of-vegetables-natu_lvwqkfm.png",
                            "active": true
                        },
                        "sizes": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:47:55.172720+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:47:55.172755+05:30",
                            "size": "medium"
                        },
                        "brand_name": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:46:44.445296+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:46:44.445328+05:30",
                            "name": "NA"
                        },
                        "uom": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-06-02T13:49:10.746284+05:30",
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-02T13:49:10.746317+05:30",
                            "name": "Kilogram",
                            "short_name": "Kg"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using ListView.builder to wrap your content instead of using for loop